# Why does Heroku Node/Express site give CORS header error on all computers except development machine?

Tags: node.js, express, session, heroku, cookies

I'm trying to get a test React frontend and Node/Express backend to correctly set session cookies at Heroku.

This frontend/backend work locally.

This frontend/backend work at Heroku in every browser on my development machine.

But on every other machine I have tested (Windows, Ubuntu), I get this Cross-Origin-Request-Blocked error:

[image]

Here is the backend code, where I configure CORS origin correctly:

```
import express from 'express'
import cors from 'cors'
import morgan from 'morgan'
import session from 'express-session';
import dotenv from 'dotenv';
import cookieParser from 'cookie-parser';

dotenv.config();
const app = express();

app.use(morgan("dev"));
app.set('trust proxy', 1);
app.use(cors({
    origin: process.env.FRONTEND_ORIGIN,
    credentials: true
}));

app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(session({
    name: 'testsession',
    secret: 'h$lYS$cr§t!',
    resave: true,
    saveUninitialized: true,
    cookie: {
        httpOnly: true,
        maxAge: 60 * 60 * 24,
        sameSite: process.env.NODE_ENV === "production" ? "none" : "lax",
        secure: process.env.NODE_ENV === "production"
    }
}))

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
    let user = req.session.user;
    if (!user) {
        res.json({ message: `${(new Date()).toISOString()}: nobody is logged in` })
    } else {
        res.json({ message: `${(new Date()).toISOString()}: ${user} is logged in` })
    }
});

app.get('/login', (req, res) => {
    req.session.user = "user001"
    res.json({
        message: `${(new Date()).toISOString()}: ${req.session.user} is now logged in`
    })
})

app.get('/logout', (req, res) => {
    req.session.destroy();
    res.json({ message: `${(new Date()).toISOString()}: user logged out` })
});

const PORT = process.env.PORT || 3011
app.listen(PORT, () => {
    console.log(`API listening on http://localhost:${PORT}`);
});
```

Here is my frontend code:

```
import { useState } from 'react';
import './App.scss';

function App() {
    const [message, setMessage] = useState('click a button');
    const backendUrl = process.env.REACT_APP_BACKEND_URL;

    const handle_checkuser = async () => {
        const requestOptions = {
            method: 'GET',
            credentials: 'include'
        };
        const response = await fetch(backendUrl, requestOptions);
        const data = await response.json();
        setMessage(data.message);
    }

    const handle_login = async () => {
        const requestOptions = {
            method: 'GET',
            credentials: 'include'
        };
        const response = await fetch(`${backendUrl}/login`, requestOptions);
        const data = await response.json();
        setMessage(data.message);
    }

    const handle_logout = async () => {
        const requestOptions = {
            method: 'GET',
            credentials: 'include'
        };
        const response = await fetch(`${backendUrl}/logout`, requestOptions);
        const data = await response.json();
        setMessage(data.message);
    }

    return (
        <div className="App">
            <div><button onClick={handle_checkuser}>checkuser</button></div>
            <div><button onClick={handle_login}>login</button></div>
            <div><button onClick={handle_logout}>logout</button></div>
            <div>{message}</div>
        </div>
    );
}

export default App;
```

**Why would it be getting this CORS error with some machines and not others?**

Backend:

- https://github.com/edwardtanguay/et-cookietest-backend
- https://et-cookietest-backend.herokuapp.com

[image]

Frontend:

- https://github.com/edwardtanguay/et-cookietest-frontend
- https://et-cookietest-frontend.herokuapp.com

[image]

## ADDENDUM

I also noticed that on every other machine except for my development machine, the HTTP connection is not secure. This seems to be the cause of the cookie-setting problem.

**But how can that be?** Why would one particular computer receive HTTPS connections from a website and others HTTP?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Your example URL is actually working correctly for me (no CORS error when hitting login button), I can also see the correct CORS headers on the response.

Can you share the response headers you are receiving on then machines getting the CORS errors? Perhaps `et-cookietest-backend.herokuapp.com` is resolving to a different server?

Comment: Hmm, that's strange that this site works for you, since except for my development machine, I get a CORS error on every other machine, Windows, Linux in every browser, and the site doesn't work on my Android phone either. I noticed that the problem seems to be that on all other computers, the connection is HTTP instead of HTTPS (I added screenshots above) and so not secure, hence a cookie doesn't get set. Is the connection HTTP on your machine or HTTPS?

Comment: I think you've actually stumbled upon the exact issue there. For me,  it worked simply because your example links were HTTPS. However, if I manually change to HTTP I can confirm I get the CORS error, and this is because the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` specifically is set to the `https` frontend domain: `https://et-cookietest-frontend.herokuapp.com`. So you can either put in a redirect to always use HTTPS (probably best approach) or allow either HTTP or S in the allowed origins.